# How to design multiple objects as shown in JSON mapping under same class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have a requirement where I need to implement a JSON response like below,

```
{
  "group":{
    "name": "MyGroup"
  }
  "members": {
    "member1" : {
      "memberCity": "Mumbai",
      "memberName": "Ajay"
    },
    "member2" : {
      "memberCity": "Banglore",
      "memberName": "Vijay"
    },
    "member3" : {
      "memberCity": "Chennai",
      "memberName": "Sujay"
    }
}
```

What I am doing right now is I have the response model which takes in both the classes,
Group
Members

Members class has multiple Member objects like below,

```
public class Members{

@JsonProperty("member1")
private Member member1;

@JsonProperty("member2")
private Member member2;

@JsonProperty("member3")
private Member member3;

//getters and setters
}
```

When I am saving the group, I am getting the group object back and fetching the members, creating new ones, setting them up and setting them back to response.

```
Set<MemberEntity> createdGroupMembers = createdGroup.getMembers();
Members allGroupMembers = new Members();
List<Member> allMembers = new ArrayList<>();

for (MemberEntity mem : createdGroupMembers) {
Member groupMember = new Member();
groupMember.setMemberName(mem.getMemberName();
groupMember.setMemberCity(mem.getMemberCity();
allMembers.add(groupMember);
}

allGroupMembers.setMember1(allMembers.get(0));
allGroupMembers.setMember2(allMembers.get(1));

response.setMembers(allGroupMembers);
```

But I don't think this is a good way to implement this. Any suggestions about how this can be implemented in a better way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you change the type of `memebers` to an `array` it could be easier to handle and maintain. The output json would become:

```
{
"group":{
"name": "MyGroup"
}
"members": [  // changed this from object to array.
"member1" : {
  "memberCity": "Mumbai",
  "memberName": "Ajay"
},
"member2" : {
  "memberCity": "Banglore",
  "memberName": "Vijay"
},
"member3" : {
  "memberCity": "Chennai",
  "memberName": "Sujay"
}
  ]
}
```

And then you can define the members as

```
@JsonProperty("members")
private ArrayList<Member> membersList;
```

Then it will be easier to add members to that list with

```
membersList.add(new Member());
```

Comment: I also thought of the same, tried too. But the issue with this is, how do I name individual members with json value like member1, member2, member3 etc. Can we generate @JsonProperty dynamically for such cases?

Comment: You can use indexes rather then individual names for this. e.g the 0 index will be member1 and 1 index will be member 2

Comment: But then the expected JSON structure is not met. The expected JSON will then be processed by next service. I cant make the changes on my own like that. Thats why need to achieve this in the right way.